# Accessing a php variable value in html <p> </p> tag I

Tags: php, html, variables, xampp

I have a file checkbalance.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>CHECK BALANCE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<img class="image" src="BITCOIN.jpg" height="100" width="100%" />

<ul class="nav" id="">
<li><a href="navbar.html">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.html">Logout</a></li>
</ul> 


<ul class="nav2">
<li><a href="myprofile.html">My Profile</a></li> 
<li><a href="">Order Chequebook/Passbook</a></li>
<li><a href="">Transactions</a></li>
<li><a href="">EFT</a></li>
<li><a href="">Change Password</a></li>
</ul>

<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Failed to connect to         
MySQL: " . mysql_error($con));

//select db
$db=mysqli_select_db($con,'sample1') or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: 
MySQL: " . mysql_error($con));

$query="SELECT BALANCE FROM ac_holders WHERE username='$_POST[username]'"; 
$data = mysqli_query ($con,$query)or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
$bal=$row['BALANCE'];
?>


<div class="text">
</br></br>
<h1> Your account balance is Rs.<?php echo $bal;?>
</h1>
</br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In here I'm not able to display my balance on the webpage inside

tags using echo function of php[Here's an image of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zxvQ.png). The only thing that gets displayed is:   Your account balance is Rs.
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!!

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`. And sql injection.

Comment: pls be more precise Im new to php and html

Comment: mysql and mysqli  work in other files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sample1");    
$query="SELECT BALANCE FROM ac_holders WHERE username='".$_POST[username]."'"; 
$data = $con->query($query);
$row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$bal=$row['BALANCE'];
?>
```

either use mysql statements or mysqli statements. mysqli is recommended because mysql is deprecated